# Rails adding whitespace in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

Okay I have faced this sort of problem below and every single time all I have had do is just make haml not sanitize the output but this isn't working. I have tried using raw, html safe but neither of those helped.

Here is what I am calling

```
def call_form 
  "SOME STRING #{"LOL"} SOME OTHER STRING"
end
```

And in my view I use `!= call_form`

and this is the output in HTML:

```
"
      SOME STRING LOL SOME OTHER STRING
      "
```

How do I get rid of all that whitespace that rails keeps adding

Comment: Why not just place the variable in line by using #{LOL}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with my form. I had forgotten to close an element in my HTML which is why it was the BROWSER that was actually adding the space. Thanks for your help anyways though. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all whitespace you can use [strip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-strip):

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > call_form = "
1.9.3p194 :002">       SOME STRING LOL SOME OTHER STRING
1.9.3p194 :003">       "
 => "\n      SOME STRING LOL SOME OTHER STRING\n      " 
1.9.3p194 :004 > call_form.strip
 => "SOME STRING LOL SOME OTHER STRING"
```

Comment: That is not what the problem is. The string that appears in my views is "SOME STRING LOL SOME OTHER STRING" but when I try to output it, rails or something is adding the space.